# Why were there only two tablets in the ark?

Tags: melachim-kings-book-of, ark-aron-kodesh

In [book 1 of Melachim (Kings) Chapter 8](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt09a08.htm#9) it says that there were only 2 tablets in the Ark.
What happened to the Mon (manna) and Moses' staff? Weren't they supposed to be in there as well?

Comment: Why do you think those things were in there as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meforshim explain that it was put "in front of" the ark, not inside the ark. Thus, it was in a separate container. As shown in Yirmiyahu 2:31, it was brought out then to show them. Rav Hirsch says in Beshalach 16:34

> As Hashem had commanded Moshe long before, at the first sending of the
>   Manna, later on when the ark of the tablets of the covenant was in
>   existence, Aharon laid the flask of Manna in front of it.

[Rashi on 16:33](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9877#showrashi=true) says

> **and deposit it before the Lord:** Before the Ark. This verse was not said until the Tent of Meeting was built, but it was written here in
>   the section dealing with the manna. —

The Gemara says that either the two sets of tablets (whole and broken) or only the whole tablets were in the [Ark](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/Judaism/ark.html)

> The contents of the Ark has been debated through the centuries. The
>   general consensus is that the first tablets containing the Ten
>   Commandments, which were broken by Moses, and the second tablets,
>   which remained intact, were contained in the Ark (Bava Batra 14b).
>   According to one opinion in the Talmud, both Tablets were together in
>   the Ark; according to another, there were two Arks, and each contained
>   one set of Tablets (Berakhot 8b).

Note that the text in the Talmud Bavli says that both luchos were in the same ark. However, the citation is brought to show that the manna was not in the ark and that is the quote as written.

The [Yerushalmi in Shekalim](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r2506.htm) says explicitly that there were two arks, one for each set of luchos but there are rabbanan who say there was only one Ark containing both

> דף כד,ב פרק ו הלכה א גמרא  התורה נתונה בתוכו ואחד שהיו שברי לוחות
>   נתונין בתוכו זה שהיתה התורה נתונה בתוכו היה מונח באהל מועד הדא הוא
>   דכתיב (במדבר יד) וארון ברית ה' ומשה לא משו מקרב המחנה זה שהיו שברי
>   לוחות נתונין בתוכו היה נכנס ויוצא עמהן ופעמים שהיה מתראה עמהן ורבנן
>   אמרי ארון א' היה ופעם אחת יצא בימי עלי ונשבה
>
> Daf 24b, Perek 6 Halacha 1  The torah was placed in it and one held
>   the broken Luchos in it. The one that had the Torah (whole luchos) in
>   it stayed in the Ohel Moed as it says (Bamidbar 14) "and the aron of
>   the bris and Moshe did not move from the midst of the camp" The one
>   that held the broken luchos would come in and go out with them and at
>   times was seen among them There are rabbis who say that there was only
>   one aron and one time it was removed in the time of Eli and captured
>   [by the P'lishtim].

Comment: I thought the two Arks idea is a Yerushalmi idea only,are you sure its in bavli?

Comment: That was the quote from the Jewish Virtual library. I do not have a copy of the Yerushalmi. Art Scroll has the line at the top of Brachos 8b2 that Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi  speaks about a talmid chacham who has forgotten his learning that both were in the ark. It is just a one line reference. I do not know why they use that as a reference to the two arks. My point was just to show that the man was not inside but was kept outside.

Comment: @sam See the previous comment. I will add a note to the answer

Answer (score 2):

[Radak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Kimhi) in his commentary to this verse says that it proves that there was no Torah scroll or broken tablets in the Ark:

> זה ראייה כי לא היו בארון לא שברי לוחות ולא ס״ת וארון שבו ס״ת נראה כי נתנוהו באוצרות בית ה' עם אהל מועד ועם הכלים וכן נראה מדברי חלקיהו הכהן ס״ת מצאתי בבית ה' נראה כי לא היה במקום שהיו רגילים בו ולא היו יודעים אותו שם באותו הדור

[Ibn Kaspi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Caspi) in his commentary says that it means that the Torah scroll and the broken tablets were in a different ark, perhaps even in a different building:

> מבואר מזה כי לא היו שם שברי לוחות גם לא ספר התורה אבל היה זה בארון אחר ואולי היה כל זה בבית אחר ג"כ

[Ralbag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gersonides) in his commentary says that it means that there was nothing else of the Torah in the Ark besides the tablets, but there were other things that the Torah says were there such as Aaron's staff and the jar of *man*:

> זה לא ישלול שלא היו שם הדברים שנזכרו בתורה שהם מונחים בו כמו מטה אהרן וצנצנת המן אך שלל בזה שלא היה שם מהתורה רק עשרת הדברים כי הם מקיפים בכח על התורה כמו שבארנו בפרשה יתרו

[Malbim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malbim) in his commentary argues that according to rules of linguistics and logic the verse consists of a double negative, so it actually means the opposite – that there *were* other things in the Ark:

> לדעת חז״ל היו שם ג"כ שברי לוחות או ס"ת מונחת (ופליגי בזה ר"מ ור"י בב"ב דף י"ד) ולדעת כולם היה שם עוד דבר לבד מן הלוחות ודייקו ממ"ש אין בארון רק הוה מיעוט אחר מיעוט ואין מיעוט אחר מיעוט אלא לרבות והדבר מבואר אצלי בכללי הלשון כי לא נמצא בשום מקום בתנ"ך מלת רק אחר שלילה שאחר שלילה בא תמיד מלת כי אם (אין זה כי אם בית אלהים אם תצאו מזה כי אם בבוא אחיכם הקטן הנה וכדומה) כי מלת רק הוא שלילה בפני עצמו בלא מלת אין ולפ"ז יש פה זרות בלשון שהיל"ל אין בארון כי אם שני לוחות או שיאמר רק שני לוחות היו בארון וזה כלל בהגיון ששלילה אחר שלילה דינה כמשפט מחייב כמו ראובן אינו חכם הוא שלילה ראובן אינו בלתי חכם הוא חיוב ור"ל ראובן הוא חכם וכן במ״ש אין בארון רק שני לוחות פירוש שלא רק שני לוחות היו בארון כי היו שם עוד דברים ובכ״ז מפשטות הלשון שמשמע שרק שני לוחות היה מבואר שהדברים שהיו שם עוד היו ענין אחד עם הלוחות והם השברי לוחות או הס"ת שכל מה שכתוב בס"ת נכלל בעשרת הדברות כמ״ש הקדמונים